# What is the difference between creating a menu with .getUI().createMenu() and .addMenu()?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

What is the difference between these two ways of getting the same thing (a new menu item)?

#### Version 1

```
 function onOpen(e) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('My Menu')
       .addItem('My Menu Item', 'myFunction')
       .addSeparator()
       .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Submenu')
           .addItem('One Submenu Item', 'mySecondFunction')
           .addItem('Another Submenu Item', 'myThirdFunction'))
       .addToUi();
 }
```

#### Version 2

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "My Menu Item", functionName: "myFunction"}]
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("My Menu", menu);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### addMenu

This is a method of Spreadsheet class, i.e., it only applies to spreadsheets. All it does is add a new menu item with second-level submenus. On the upside, the syntax is very simple.

#### getUi

This method is currently available for three apps: SpreadsheetApp, DocumentApp, and FormApp. It returns an instance of [user interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) which can be used for more than just adding a menu item. One can show alerts, prompts, dialogs, and even add an interactive sidebar with custom content. Also, the menu creating options are richer: they allow separators and nested submenus. There are special add-on menus, too. Accordingly, the syntax is more verbose.

#### Conclusion

Neither of two methods is deprecated; use whichever fits your goal better.

Answer (score -1):

Another difference: you cannot add submenus (child menu items under parent menu items) with addMenu. This limitation pretty much self-deprecates the addMenu method despite the cool syntax.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer should be edited to clarify the "difference" from [@user79865's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/91204/) You state "you cannot add submenus" yet the other answer indicates that  you can add a "new menu item" (parent) with "second-level submenus"  seems like a contradiction or one or both of the answers are unclear.