# Copy a row to another sheet if condition is met?

Tags: google-sheets

If a cell in a row has any of the four exact words: `text`, `number`, `date` or `time`, how can I make it paste that row into the "next available (blank) row" in another sheet (same workbook)?

As I enter row entries into the sheet called "MASTER", I'd like it to auto populate the sheet "RECORDS" with exactly the same information.

Comment: Related: [Copy a row and add to the bottom of a list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92385/88163)

Answer (score 2):

One way might be to flag the rows that are relevant, say with:

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXTJOIN(,1,A1:G1),"text|number|date|time")
```

in `MASTER` copied down to suit, and then select on the basis of those flags, say with:

```
=query(MASTER!A:H,"select * where H=TRUE")
```

in `RECORDS`.

[REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
[TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Assumes any addition to `RECORDS` will be from the bottom of `MASTER`, or not required in `RECORDS`.

Comment: Many thanks pnuts - so the first formula gos into "MASTER" - but where? I have a cell in each row (column J) containing the trigger keywords ("text", "number", "date" or "time") which I select from a drop-down menu within the cell, and preceding that, the previous cells in the row (A2:I2) contain other info that I want to copy into the sheet "RECORDS". So where do I enter each of these formula's please.